# Spring Rest Service not working

Tags: java, spring

[image]I am new to spring and trying to develop a basic web service using spring(with maven). I am unable to make out whats the error:
Here are the files I have:

web.xml  (is under WEB-INF)

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC  
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >  

<web-app>  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
  <servlet>  
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>  
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  
 </servlet-class>  
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

---

springrest-servlet.xml(is under WEB-INF)

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample." />
```

CountryController.java

```
package com.sample.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sample.model.Country;  

@RestController  
public class CountryController {  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")  
 public List<Country> getCountries()  
 {  
  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries=createCountryList();  
  return listOfCountries;  
 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")  
 public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id)  
 {  
  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries=createCountryList();  
  for (Country country: listOfCountries) {  
   if(country.getId()==id)  
    return country;  
  }  

  return null;  
 }  

// Utiliy method to create country list.  
 public List<Country> createCountryList()  
 {  
  Country indiaCountry=new Country(1, "India");  
  Country chinaCountry=new Country(4, "China");  
  Country nepalCountry=new Country(3, "Nepal");  
  Country bhutanCountry=new Country(2, "Bhutan");  


  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries.add(indiaCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(chinaCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(nepalCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(bhutanCountry);  
  return listOfCountries;  
 }  
}
```

Country.java

```
package com.sample.model;



public class Country {

    int id;
    String name;


    public Country(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

### }

I run the same on tomcat, and then , the response shows No Data Found.

Comment: Post an image *the response shows No Data Found.*

Comment: Do you have `contextConfigLocation` in web.xml. Because you have a different name for that one (`springrest-servlet.xml`) where do you configure it. Or do you use `WebApplicationInitializer` to initialize it?

Comment: I have given the name of dispatcher servlet, what is context configLocation for, please tell.

Comment: As part of the servlet initialization in `web.xml` you need to tell Spring to bootstrap Spring application by specifying the name and location of your `springrest-servlet.xml` file. But I cannot see that configuration in your web.xml file. See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) for more information

Comment: You can omit the above specific configuration as Spring MVC will look for a `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file by default. But your file name is different and need to be listed in web.xml as it is out of convention over configuration.

Comment: Have added     '<init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/springrest.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>'    , but still same issue.

Comment: Can you please try localhost:8080/springrest/countries. We usually get this error when the resource is not found on the mentioned path and by the looks of your web.xml you are using springrest in your web.xml and I dont see SpringSample mentioned anywhere

Comment: springrest is the name of dispatcher-servlet for spring framework. SpringSample is the name of the war file when deployed in tomcat. The web.xml file directs it to the dispatcher servlet named springrest. It should not come in url.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Instead of deploying it in Tomcat via eclipse, I exported the war file and deployed it independently and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ur bas package must be somthing like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
```

and not

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample." />
```

Comment: Thanx for the error. But unfortunately, the response is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet mapping is wrong also, instead of `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` it should be `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` as specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html).